# CLLocation enviar ubicacion dependiendo del curso

Tags: swift

Estoy realizando una app de Geolocalizacion con swift, utilizando CLLocation y socket.io, luego de obtener los resultados dibuja una grafica teniendo en cuenta las ubicaciones que envió el dispositivo

```
func getTramaGPS2(tipo type:String, location: CLLocation)->String {

        var speed: String = "10"
        var course: String = "10"
        
        course = String(Int(location.course))
        speed =  String((Int(location.speed  * 3.6)))
        
        self.envioUbicacion
        print("Socket ----> SP CO ACTUALIZADO \(speed)  \(course)")

    }
```

Un ejemplo de como sale el gráfico en una curva :

[image: Respuesta Obtenida]

Lo que quiero hacer, es que dependiendo del curso, pueda identificar una curva y pueda mandar una nueva localización en esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas Gracias por su tiempo

Comment: Cada qué tiempo obtienes la ubicación? Si no tienes la coordenada de la esquina en donde gira por eso al dibujar la línea une esos puntos y se va por encima. Intentaste detectar si gira hacia la derecha o izquierda con [Core Motion](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion)?

Comment: La ubicación la obtengo cada 5 segundos, y sobre core motion no lo eh intentado, como soy nuevo en swift desconocía su existencia.